# Dúvida com criação de arquivo XML

Tags: c#, xml

Tenho um programa que cria um arquivo XML utilizando o XmlTextWriter, segue o exemplo

```
public static void testeGerarXml()
{
    using (var xml = new XmlTextWriter(@"c:\Gustavo\teste.xml", Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        xml.WriteStartDocument();
        xml.Formatting = Formatting.None;

        xml.WriteStartElement("teste");
        {
            xml.WriteStartElement("endereco");
            {
                xml.WriteElementString("cep", "12345678");
                xml.WriteElementString("logradouro", "rua teste");
                xml.WriteElementString("numero", "112233");
            }
            xml.WriteEndElement();

            xml.WriteStartElement("contato");
            {
                xml.WriteElementString("celular", "(19) 9 9999-9999");
                xml.WriteElementString("email", "teste@teste.com");
                xml.WriteElementString("nome", "gustavo");
            }
            xml.WriteEndElement();
        }

        xml.WriteFullEndElement();
        xml.Close();
    }
}
```

Gostaria de criar funções para facilitar a manutenção do código, cada função seria responsável por criar um nó, como no exemplo.

```
public static void testeGerarXml()
{
    using (var xml = new XmlTextWriter(@"c:\Gustavo\teste.xml", Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        xml.WriteStartDocument();
        xml.Formatting = Formatting.None;

        xml.WriteStartElement("teste");
        {
            funcaoCriaEndereco();

            funcaoCriaContato();
        }

        xml.WriteFullEndElement();
        xml.Close();
    }
}


private static string funcaoCriaEndereco()
{
    using (var str = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (var xml = new XmlTextWriter(str))
        {
            xml.WriteStartDocument();
            xml.WriteStartElement("endereco");
            {
                xml.WriteElementString("cep", "12345678");
                xml.WriteElementString("logradouro", "rua teste");
                xml.WriteElementString("numero", "112233");
            }
            xml.WriteEndElement();

            return str.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Até criei uma função que retorna a string do nó gerado, mas não sei como escrever esse nó no arquivo principal xml, alguém sabe uma maneira de fazer isso funcionar?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adorei sua ideia, mas a abordagem não está boa. Use *extensions* para o `XmlWriter` que funcionará melhor:

```
public static void testeGerarXml()
{
    using (var xml = new XmlTextWriter(@"c:\Gustavo\teste.xml", Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        xml.WriteStartDocument();
        xml.Formatting = Formatting.None;

        var endereco = new Endereco 
        {
            Cep = "12345",
            Logradouro = "Rua Tal",
            Numero = "345"
        };

        var contato = new Contato
        {
            Celular = "(11) 92222-2222",
            Email = "gustavo@gustavo.com",
            Nome = "Gustavo"
        };

        xml.EscreverEndereco(endereco);
        xml.EscreverContato(contato);

        xml.WriteFullEndElement();
        xml.Close();
    }
}
```

Os métodos:

```
public static class XmlWriterExtensions
{
    public static void EscreverEndereco(this XmlTextWriter xml, Endereco endereco)
    {
        // xml.WriteStartDocument();
        xml.WriteStartElement("endereco");
        {
            xml.WriteElementString("cep", endereco.Cep);
            xml.WriteElementString("logradouro", endereco.Logradouro);
            xml.WriteElementString("numero", endereco.Numero);
        }

        xml.WriteEndElement();
    }


    private static void EscreverContato(this XmlTextWriter xml, Contato contato)
    {
        // xml.WriteStartDocument();
        xml.WriteStartElement("contato");
        {
            xml.WriteElementString("celular", contato.Celular);
            xml.WriteElementString("email", contato.Email);
            xml.WriteElementString("nome", contato.Nome);
        }

        xml.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

Não esqueça de declarar `Endereco` e `Contato`.

Comment: Como funciona esse _Extensions_ que você citou? É só criar a classe _XmlWriterExtensions_ que o _XmlTextWriter_ já reconhece os métodos da classe como um método dele? Já já vou testar esse código, mas já agradeço peka ajuda

Comment: "Como funciona esse Extensions que você citou? É só criar a classe XmlWriterExtensions que o XmlTextWriter já reconhece os métodos da classe como um método dele?", sim, você está estendendo `XmlWriter` com mais dois métodos novos que são reconhecidos até pelo Intellisense.

Comment: Essa ideia com essa resposta ficou sensacional.

Comment: Muito bom, funcionou aqui. Eu não sabia desse _Extensions_, li a respeito e  é bem útil, valew ai pela ajuda. Abraços